# Where can I find worm traffic sample?

Tags: malware, ids, intrusion

I have a program that has to detect scanning activity of worms.

I need some samples of worms' traffic (pcap files) to try the program, and notes about the procedures which must be taken when running such files to keep my computer safe.

Are there any safe capture files that contain the scanning activity only without the worm payload? There is a sample capture for slammer worm at wireshark.org, but when I tried to open it I got a warning. What I should do in this case??

Comment: The [Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures) has some nice samples, two under Viruses and worms.

Comment: Thanks a lot,yes ,as I mentioned in my question, I saw them but when I tried to open the file of slammer.pcap i've got a warning and I was afraid from open it, is there any procedures or measrements should be taken when work with these type of files,are they harmful to my pc? do you know further sites have these type of traffic?

Comment: My first reaction is that your anti virus application alerts you that the contents look very much like the Slammer worm. Which really should leave no minds blown. You'll probably be safe. If you're scared, get yourself a [Virtual Machine](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and [a free operating system that supports Wireshark](http://www.ubuntu.com/download). If anything happens within the VM it is limited to the VM only.

Comment: if you have a pcap already then there shouldn't be anything to be afraid of. If you're super paranoid though you can always using `tshark` to convert the pcap to plain text.

Comment: @Henning Klevjer: Hi , I opened the suggested samples, they are also not showing what I'm lookong for.the first one contains 1 packet only so it useless because I want to notice scanning activity and the other one contains anomaly in the packet payload for one packet which is not targeted in my program, any other suggestions??   :-(

Comment: No more suggestions than trying to get infected and Wireshark it.

Comment: My question here (and the answers I got) might be of some help - http://security.stackexchange.com/q/15235/9778

Comment: Thanks a lot @pnp it looks great, I didn't check yet but I will feed you back with what is happedn.someone else give me another site for dataset didn't be mentioned in your question answers and may help you: [iscx](http://www.iscx.ca/datasets)

Comment: Yes I would love to have your feedback on their utility and I have tried ISCX's datasets as well...

Comment: @pnpI'd like to ask about this. My program is small and targeting the scan activity phase of the worm, is it useful to use these large data set ?? and most of the dataset I saw is talking about DoS and I don't find one which targeting worm, any suggestion or advice?

Comment: Leena- your comment never reached me since you used the wrong name with '@'. In my question, the accepted answer has some good links like the pcapr link. Something like the Pytbull project may help as well. As for your question- DoS datasets and other such big datasets are not of much use to you in my opinion. Typically scan activity of a worm doesn't require GBs of datasets. Another link: http://vx.netlux.org/index.html. It was a good source for malware samples. The site is presently inactive, but you may want to follow it...

Comment: Thanks a lot @pnp and sorry for the mistake. Your feedback is useful. Thanks again.Regards

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I would install VMs using Virtualbox and create a standalone internal network. Then, I would infect one machine with Slammer and capture the traffic.

If you are going to be doing security research, then you will need to set up a lab like this and get your hands dirty. Your learning will be so much better.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sandbox tool such as [Cuckoo](http://www.cuckoosandbox.org/) which will allow you to run your malware in a safe environment. This will [provide](http://docs.cuckoosandbox.org/en/latest/usage/results/#dump-pcap) a pcap file containing the resulting network traffic.

In terms of services out there that provide the pcap files for worms, I'm not aware of any. [Malwr](http://malwr.com) (which uses cuckoo) will give you an overview of some of the network traffic but not the whole file.